# Desktop HTML + CSS + JS application? How this is possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, desktop-application

I've recently fell in love with Nitro (http://nitrotasks.com), but what got me very curious was that it was written in HTML, CSS and Javascript, yet, it is packaged as a multi-platform binary! How is this possible? Which toolkit are they using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on their [Launchpad repository](https://code.launchpad.net/nitrotasks) for Ubuntu, they are using [Quickly](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/08/quickly-new-rails-like-rapid-development-tools-for-ubuntu/).

For Chrome and Firefox, based on the [Nitro GitHub page](https://github.com/stayradiated/Nitro), it seems that they are just deploying it as a browser plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the Nitro website, and it doesn't look like it is a multi-platform binary, after all. It looks like they have a version for Linux/Ubuntu, and also an extension (plugin) for Chrome.  They also have a web version and a Firefox plugin, which isn't available yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't exactly an answer to your question, but I am assuming you're asking because you consider doing a similar thing yourself in which case it might be worthwhile to check out http://appjs.org/ which makes exactly this possible. Please do realize a lot might change and you should only use that **if and only if** you're willing to adapt to those change in the future.